# Why can't the input tag have the value of a variable? php

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
$varone = "Hello World";
$str = '<input type="text" width="200px";   name="worksvr" maxlength="999"  value='.$varone.' >';
echo $str;
?>
```

that's my php code and I want the input to have the value of $varone but for some reason when I run the code it only outputs Hello and does not include World.Any advice would really be helpful thank you in advance

I tried many things including maxlength but that did not help at all.Please any help would be useful thank you.

Comment: You need quotes around the value when there's a space... `value="foo bar"`

Comment: ``value="'.$varone.'">``

Comment: You also need to escape. Example `value="' . htmlspecialchars($var) . '"` in case that string may contains some characters like `<'">`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is this

```php
<?php
$varone = "Hello World";
$str = '<input type="text" width="200px";   name="worksvr" maxlength="999"  value="'.$varone.'" >';
echo $str;
?>
```

Note the quotes around the output of `$varone`

See: https://onlinephp.io/c/b007f